# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'. Stuck in a loop

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis-7, web-config

The complete error is:

> Cannot open database "*Name*" requested by the login. The login
>   failed. Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM'.

I have tried almost every solution available on here. already tried changing Integrated Security to false and true and sspi but still nothing. changing pool to `ApplicationPoolIdentity` just changes error to

> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL/*name*'

I have also tried adding those names to the sql server management studio under login and giving them sysadmin and public roles, also gave them db_read and write or whatever they were called.

Changing identity impersonate to true from false gives

> Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\IUSR'

or something similiar so I'm kind of stuck in a loop (which i have added to logins).

Now I'm not the author of this asp.net webapp and am just tasked with deploying the published files on this pc so I have no idea if I'm missing something obvious. (probably not cause the lead developer tried to get it working yesterday for about 5 hours).

By the way the app totally works everywhere else it just hates me.

Comment: Do you install SQL Server and IIS on the same machine?

Answer (score 0):

Missing an ODBC?
and make sure SQL is set to Mixed mode. SQL and Windows Authorization.
make sure the SQL server agent is set to Windows. Log On As. under SQL Server Configuration Manager.

Answer (score -1):

create an account on SQL server (login) and write it in the connection string ( https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/connection-to-a-sql-server-instance/ )

`Server=myServerName\myInstanceName;Database=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;
Password=myPassword;`